# OpenCV trackbar assertion failed error

Tags: python, opencv, trackbar

I want to do foreground segmentation using opencv. I have written code that has trackbars so that I can find optimal parameters for the segmentation. When the code is executed it works, the images are shown with contours marked and etc. But when I try to move bars on the track bar. I'm getting the following error.

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /feedstock_root/build_artefacts/opencv_1523502125490/work/opencv-3.4.1/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 356
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forgroundsegmentation.py", line 17, in foreground_segment
    cv2.imshow('brightness preprocess', tmp)
```

This is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

winName = "ForeGround Segment"

def foreground_segment(src, a=None,b=None, useEqualize=1, blurSize=21, th1=None, brightness=None):
    winName = "ForeGround Segment"
    tmp = brightness

    if (blurSize >= 3):
        blurSize += (1 - blurSize % 2)
        tmp = cv2.GaussianBlur(tmp, (blurSize, blurSize), 0)
    if (useEqualize):
        tmp = cv2.equalizeHist(tmp)

    cv2.imshow('brightness preprocess', tmp)
    #cv2.imwrite('../BrightnessPreprocess.png', tmp)

    ret, tmp = cv2.threshold(tmp, th1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.imshow(winName, tmp)

    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(tmp, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    dst = src

    #print(contours)    

    maxDim = 0
    largest = -1
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        cv2.drawContours(dst, contours, largest, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        dim = len(contours[i])
        if (dim > maxDim):
            maxDim = dim
            largest = i

    img_mask = np.zeros(src.shape, np.uint8)

    if (largest >= 0):
        theImg = contours[largest]
        cv2.polylines(dst, theImg, True, (0, 255,0), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(img_mask, contours, largest, 255, -1)

    cv2.imshow("Result Mask", img_mask)
    cv2.imshow("Result Contour", dst)
    #cv2.imwrite("../img_mask.png", img_mask)
    #cv2.imwrite("../result.png", dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = cv2.imread('frontal.png')
    print(src.shape)
    src = cv2.resize(src, (int(src.shape[0]/3), int(src.shape[1]/3)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    #src = cv2.resize(src, (500, 500), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow(winName, src)
    dst = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hsv_planes = cv2.split(dst)
    brightness = hsv_planes[2]
    useEqualize = 1
    blurSize = 21
    th1 = int(33.0 * 255 / 100)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Equalize", winName, useEqualize, 1, foreground_segment)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Blur Sigma", winName, blurSize, 100, foreground_segment)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold", winName, th1, 255, foreground_segment)

    foreground_segment(src ,0, 0, useEqualize, blurSize, th1, brightness=brightness)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

I think I'm doing everything correctly. Can someone point me out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You need to use `cv2.getTrackbarPos()` to see changes as you move the slider!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, building a segmentation tool of this type is a great idea!!

The code you have provided only creates the trackbars using `cv2.createTrackbar()`. In order to use them you need to implement `cv2.getTrackbarPos()` to get different values as you slide the trackbar.

I have made modified the same code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

winName = "ForeGround Segment"

def foreground_segment(im, brightness, useEqualize=1, blurSize=21, th1=None):
    winName = "ForeGround Segment"
    tmp = brightness

    if (blurSize >= 3):
        blurSize += (1 - blurSize % 2)
        tmp = cv2.GaussianBlur(tmp, (blurSize, blurSize), 0)
    if (useEqualize):
        tmp = cv2.equalizeHist(tmp)

    cv2.imshow('brightness preprocess', tmp)
    #cv2.imwrite('../BrightnessPreprocess.png', tmp)

    ret, tmp = cv2.threshold(tmp, th1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv2.imshow('threshold', tmp)

    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(tmp, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    dst = im.copy()

    #print(contours)    

    maxDim = 0
    largest = -1
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        cv2.drawContours(dst, contours, largest, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        dim = len(contours[i])
        if (dim > maxDim):
            maxDim = dim
            largest = i

    img_mask = np.zeros(src.shape, np.uint8)

    if (largest >= 0):
        theImg = contours[largest]
        cv2.polylines(dst, theImg, True, (0, 255,0), 2)
        cv2.drawContours(img_mask, contours, largest, 255, -1)

    cv2.imshow("Result Mask", img_mask)
    cv2.imshow("Result Contour", dst)
    #cv2.imwrite("../img_mask.png", img_mask)
    #cv2.imwrite("../result.png", dst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = cv2.imread('frontal.png')
    src = cv2.resize(src, (int(src.shape[0]/3), int(src.shape[1]/3)), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    cv2.imshow(winName, src)
    dst = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hsv_planes = cv2.split(dst)
    brightness = hsv_planes[2]
    useEqualize = 1
    blurSize = 21
    th1 = int(33.0 * 255 / 100)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Equalize", winName, useEqualize, 1, foreground_segment)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Blur Sigma", winName, blurSize, 100, foreground_segment)
    cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold", winName, th1, 255, foreground_segment)

    while(1):

        #--- Using cv2.getTrackbarPos() to get values from the slider ---
        useEqualize = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Equalize', winName)
        blurSize = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Blur Sigma', winName)
        th1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('Threshold', winName)

        foreground_segment(src, brightness, useEqualize, blurSize, th1)

        #--- Press Q to quit ---            
        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I am a beginner OpenCV user.

Comment: `TypeError: foreground_segment() missing 1 required positional argument: 'brightness`.  This is the error I'm getting when I try moving the silder. But `brightness` is passed into the function as an argument. Why do you think this is happening.

Comment: @MathJunkiey Are you able to get the output?

Comment: I'm able to get the output.

Comment: You could try searching for algorithms built using CNN specifically for these kind of tasks.